# Given a matrix with respect to the standard bases of a linear transformation $T$, find the basis for which the matrix of $T$ is this.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be the linear transformation given by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & -1 \\
> 2 & 2  \\
> 0 & 3
> \end{pmatrix}$ with respect to the standard bases. Find bases for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ in which the matrix of $T$ is $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1  \\
> 0 & 0
> \end{pmatrix}.$

Denote the standard bases in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $S_2$ and $S_3$ respectively.

I know that the given matrix is $[T]_{S_3S_2}$ and we have to find $\left[T\right]_{BA}$ where $A$ and $B$ are bases in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ respectively. I tried to use the theorem $[T]_{BA} = [I]_{BS_3}[T]_{S_3S_2}[I]_{S_2A}$. I know that $[I]_{S_2A}$ is $A$ and $[I]_{BS_3}$ is $B^{-1}$. So, it can be rewritten as:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=B^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
2 & 2  \\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}A \\$$

or
$$
B\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1  \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
2 & 2  \\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}A$$

Defining $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 \\
a_3 & a_4 
\end{pmatrix}$ and B= $\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
b_4 & b_5 & b_6  \\
b_7 & b_8 & b_9
\end{pmatrix}$ and then solving, I get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
b_1 & b_2 \\
b_4 & b_5  \\
b_7 & b_8
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 - a_3 & a_2 -a_4 \\
2a_1 + 2a_3 & 2a_2 +2a_4  \\
3a_3 & 3a_4
\end{pmatrix}$$

I don't think method is correct. Where am I going wrong here and how do I solve this problem?

Comment: Let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^2$  and take a vector $u$ of $\mathbb R^3$ s.t. $\{T(e_1),T(e_2),u\}$ is free. Then $T$ has the form you wish in those basis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e_1=(1,0),e_2=(0,1)$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $f_1=(1,0,0),f_2=(0,1,0),f_3=(0,0,1)$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Since $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is the linear transformation given by the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -1 \\
 2 & 2  \\
 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$ with respect to the standard bases. Then
\begin{align}
 (1) \ \ \ \ \ \ T(e_1)&=f_1+2f_2;\\
 (2) \ \ \ \ \ \ T(e_2)&=-f_1+2f_2+3f_3.
\end{align}
We have to find a basis $\tilde{e}_1,\tilde{e}_2$ for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\tilde{f}_1,\tilde{f}_2,\tilde{f}_3$ for $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that
\begin{align}
 (3) \ \ \ \ \ \ T(\tilde{e}_1)&=\tilde{f}_1;\\
 (4) \ \ \ \ \ \ T(\tilde{e}_2)&=\tilde{f}_2.
\end{align}
Define
\begin{align}
 (5) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \tilde{e}_1&=e_1=(1,0);\\
 (6) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \tilde{e}_2&=e_2=(0,1);\\
 (7) \ \ \ \ \ \ \tilde{f}_1&=f_1+2f_2=(1,2,0);\\
 (8) \ \ \ \ \ \ \tilde{f}_2&=-f_1+2f_2+3f_3=(-1,2,3);\\
 (9) \ \ \ \ \ \ \tilde{f}_3&=f_3=(0,0,1).
\end{align}
We can easily check that $\tilde{e}_1,\tilde{e}_2$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\tilde{f}_1,\tilde{f}_2,\tilde{f}_3$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Moreover, it is also easy to check that these basis satisfies (3-4) by substituting (5-9) into (1-2).